# Prototype chain using Object.assign and descriptors

Tags: javascript

Let's consider this situation:

```js
var firstObject = {
  set a(val) {
   this._a_ = val;
  },
  get a() {
   return this._a_;
  }
}

var secondObject = Object.assign(firstObject);

secondObject.a = 3;

console.log(secondObject.a); // 3
console.log(firstObject.a); // 3

console.log(secondObject.hasOwnProperty('a')); // true
console.log(firstObject.hasOwnProperty('a')); // true
```

Why both `firstObject` and `secondObject` returns 3? 
How prototype chaining works here?

Comment: There is no prototypal inheritance here, you're copying over a property from `FirstObject` to `SecondObject` If you want to use a prototype, look at `Object.create()` instead.

Comment: @MisterEpic: In fact, the code above isn't even doing *that*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Indeed, you are correct, an empty object should be passed as the target.

Comment: Thanks guys. Edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the first argument to `Object.assign` is the object to assign **to**. Then `Object.assign` returns a reference to that object. It assigns **from** subsequent arguments, but you aren't supplying any. So the end result is that `firstObject` and `secondObject` just point to the same object:

```js
var firstObject = {
  set a(val) {
   this._a_ = val;
  },
  get a() {
   return this._a_;
  }
}

var secondObject = Object.assign(firstObject);
console.log("Same object? " + (firstObject === secondObject));
```

You wanted:

```
var secondObject = Object.assign({}, firstObject);
// Note -------------------------^^^^
```

Also note that `Object.assign` copies the *value* of `a` from `firstObject` to that new object, not the property descriptor for it. So the `a` property on `secondObject` is just a simple property, not an accessor.

Here's a snippet with the change above, and showing the descriptors on each of the objects at the end:

```js
var firstObject = {
  set a(val) {
   this._a_ = val;
  },
  get a() {
   return this._a_;
  }
}

var secondObject = Object.assign({}, firstObject);

secondObject.a = 3;

console.log(secondObject.a); // 3
console.log(firstObject.a);  // undefined

firstObject.a = 42;
console.log(firstObject.a);  // 42
console.log(secondObject.a); // still 3

console.log(
  "firstObject's a descriptor:",
  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(firstObject, "a")
);
console.log(
  "secondObject's a descriptor:",
  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(secondObject, "a")
);
```

---

Also note that as [Mister Epic pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818541/prototype-chain-using-object-assign-and-descriptors/39818614#comment66927317_39818541), there is no real use of the prototype chain here at all. `firstObject` has an *own* property `a`, and after the copy, so does `secondObject`. `secondObject` doesn't inherit from `firstObject` or anything like that; `Object.assign` *copies* properties.

Comment: @Bergi: Heh, I meant to, must have gotten distracted. Done now.